# how to enable or disable a button on keypress event of a textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I created a TextBox :-

```
TextBox ID="TxtUname" onKeyPress="ENABLE_BTN()"
```

Now i wrote a function :-

```
script type="text/javascript"

window.onload = function() { 
        document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled = true; 
}; 
function ENABLE_BTN() {
     var EN=document.getElementById('TxtUname').value;
     if(EN=='') {
         document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled=true;
     } else {
         document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled=false;
     }
}
</script>
```

BUT STILL THE DISABLED BUTTON IS NOT GETTING ENABLED ON PRESSING ANY KEY IN THE TEXTBOX.
Can anyone tell me what i did wrong ?? Thanks in Advance

Dev..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onkeypress` doesn't work in all browsers -> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

`onkeyup` / `onkeydown` should be used ->

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/KCBzk/

HTML :

```
<input id="TxtUname" value="" onkeydown="ENABLE_BTN()"/><br>
<button id="SSAccept">Some test</button>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled = true; 
}
function ENABLE_BTN() {
     var EN=document.getElementById('TxtUname').value;
     if(EN=='') {
         document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled=true;
     } else {
         document.getElementById('SSAccept').disabled=false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Dude.. on KeyDown too dosent worked but onKeyUp worked successfully. Thanks a lot. God bless u.. But can u tell that onKeyUp will run on every browser successfully ??

Comment: @Dev what browser are you using ?

Answer (score -1):

the thing is that you need an event to invoke that function. you should monitor your textbox for change and invoke the function whenever the value changes. like using jquery

```
$("#TxtUname").keydown(function(e) { 
    if($("#TxtUname").val == '') {
        //..disable button..
    } else {
        //..enable button
    }
});
```

Comment: This is jQuery - the OP didn't say he was using jQuery

Comment: i said like using jquery . **you should monitor your textbox for change and invoke the function whenever the value changes** see